# Why are two select statements (on array of custom objects) are combined into one result?

Tags: powershell-4.0

Why are the two PowerShell "Select Name, Count" statements below (from an array of objects) combining into one result.  How can I modify to see two results, grouped at two different levels. Each select is returning the correct data, but they are combined in one common set of headings.

```
cls
$customObjectsArray = @() 

#### build a few objects for to reproduce my issue #### 
$customObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
FileName = "Demo1.odx" 
Type = "Orchestration"
Method = "GetText"
}
$customObjectsArray += $customObject

$customObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
FileName = "Demo1.odx"
Type ="Orchestration"
Method = "GetUser"
}
$customObjectsArray += $customObject

$customObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
FileName = "Demo2.btm"
Type = "Map"
Method = "GetText"
}
$customObjectsArray += $customObject


$customObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
FileType = "Demo2.btm"
Type = "Map"
Method = "GetConnString"
}
$customObjectsArray += $customObject

$customObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
FileName = "Demo4.odx"
Type = "Orchestration"
Method = "GetText"
}
$customObjectsArray += $customObject


Write-Host ""
Write-Host "============================"
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Grouped By MethodName, FileType... Count of Items = $($customObjectsArray.Count)" 
$customObjectsArray | Group Method, Type | Sort Count -Descending  | Select Name, Count 
# I tried this way as well, same result. 
#$groupdArray2 = $customObjectsArray | Group Method, Type | Sort Count -Descending 
#$result1 = $groupedArray2 | Select Name, Count 
#$result1


Write-Host ""
Write-Host "============================"
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Grouped By MethodName Only ... Count of Items = $($customObjectsArray.Count)" 
$customObjectsArray | Group Method | Sort Count -Descending  | Select Name, Count 
# I tried this way as well, same result. 
#$groupedArray1  = $customObjectsArray | Group Method | Sort Count -Descending 
#$result2 = $groupedArray1 | Select Name, Count 
#$result2
```

**Actual Output:**

```
============================

Grouped By MethodName, FileType... Count of Items = 5


============================

Grouped By MethodName Only ... Count of Items = 5
Name                   Count
----                   -----
GetText, Orchestration     2
GetUser, Orchestration     1
GetText, Map               1
GetConnString, Map         1
GetText                    3
GetUser                    1
GetConnString              1
```

**Desired Output:**

```
============================

Grouped By MethodName, FileType... Count of Items = 5

Name                   Count
----                   -----
GetText, Orchestration     2
GetUser, Orchestration     1
GetText, Map               1
GetConnString, Map         1

============================

Grouped By MethodName Only ... Count of Items = 5
Name                   Count
----                   -----
GetText                    3
GetUser                    1
GetConnString              1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--- Updated Answer ---

Getting rid of Select and replacing with Format-Table seems to have cleared up the output. I also got rid of the redundant Write-Host cmds.

---

I cleaned up your example so each object had the same properties. Then I broke down the Pipe using an intermediate variable and it seems to work fine.

```
cls
$customObjectsArray = @() 

#### build a few objects for to reproduce my issue #### 
$customObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
FileName = "Demo1.odx" 
Type     = "Orchestration"
Method   = "GetText"
}
$customObjectsArray += $customObject

$customObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
FileName = "Demo1.odx"
Type     = "Orchestration"
Method   = "GetUser"
}
$customObjectsArray += $customObject

$customObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
FileName = "Demo9.btm"
Type     = "Map"
Method   = "GetText"
}
$customObjectsArray += $customObject


$customObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
FileName = "Demo2.btm"
Type     = "Map"
Method   = "GetConnString"
}
$customObjectsArray += $customObject

$customObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
FileName = "Demo4.odx"
Type     = "Orchestration"
Method   = "GetText"
}
$customObjectsArray += $customObject

"`n`n============================`n"

'Grouped By MethodName... Count of Items = $($customObjectsArray.Count)' 
$Tally = $customObjectsArray | Group Method 
$Tally | Sort Count -Descending | FT Name, Count 

"`n`n============================`n"

'Grouped By MethodName, FileType... Count of Items = $($customObjectsArray.Count)' 
$Tally2 = $customObjectsArray | Group Method, Type
$Tally2 |  Sort Count -Descending | Ft Name, Count
```

Sample Output:

```
============================

Grouped By MethodName... Count of Items = $($customObjectsArray.Count)

Name          Count
----          -----
GetText           3
GetUser           1
GetConnString     1




============================

Grouped By MethodName, FileType... Count of Items = $($customObjectsArray.Count)

Name                   Count
----                   -----
GetText, Orchestration     2
GetUser, Orchestration     1
GetText, Map               1
GetConnString, Map         1


PS>
```

Comment: I wanted two outputs, one grouped one way, and the second grouped at a higher level (as in the "Desired Output" of my question.   Was really asking why my code did what it did?  I realize a few fields didn't match, but that was not consequential to the question.  And you have "FileType" in the group-by and "Type" in the data, so it's actually slightly worse.  We have similar backgrounds on mainframe and I remember the TRS-80, but never had one.

Comment: @NealWalters, I updated the answer. How's it look now?

Comment: Great, Thanks! But what is the essential thing that made it work?  Was it using FormatTable instead of Select?

Comment: @NealWalters, yes that is what made it work but I don't know the technical reason for it. Hopefully one of the PS Gurus will chime in with the details.